# How can i change the space in CarRacing-v0 from box to discrete?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, dqn, discrete

I wanna train my agent in CarRacing-v0 environment, but instead of box action/observation spaces
I want to use discrete spaces so I can train it with DQN algorithm.
there is a sayin in openai-gym that says: "Discreet control is reasonable in this environment as well, on/off discretisation is fine."  https://gym.openai.com/envs/CarRacing-v0/

but I dont know how to do it in code or in pragmatic way.